# Why is nest not giving me multiple datasets and operating on the entire dataframe?

Tags: r, dplyr, distinct, nest

I'm trying to make datasets for each class by using nest, and after doing so, I need to perform some computations that require me to use distinct() to avoid duplicates.

However, when I try, R seems to ignore nest and just proceeds on. As a result, I just have the overall results and just one dataframe. How do I get this to work and why is it failing?

Note: I know that, for the below simple example, I don't need to use nest and could use group_by(), but I need nest() for my actual data and am curious why it isn't working.

```
#Set up and sample data
library(tidyverse)
test_data <- tibble(id = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3),
                    class = c("h", "h", "m", "h", "s", "m", "h", "h"),
                    gender = c("m", "m", "f", "f", "f", "m", "m", "m"))

#Runs but isn't correct
nested_test <- test_data %>%
  nest(data = class) %>%
  distinct(id, gender) %>%
  count(gender)

nested_test
```

Comment: You have to make operations in the `data` column of the df. Try `mutate(nested_test = map(data, ~distinct(.x,id, gender)) %>% unnest(nested_test)`

Comment: `nest(data = class)` creates a new column called `data` - a `list`-class column. `distinct(id, gender)` drops all columns except for `id` and `gender`, so the code is interpreted as a clear instruction to drop your nested `data` column.

Comment: Could you add an example or at least describe your desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not 100% sure I understand your goal, but this code nests all columns except `class` into a separate dataframe for each `class`. Note you first specify the columns wanted, then the variable(s) to group `.by`. It then maps over each dataframe, applying `distinct()` and `count()` to each.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)

nested_test <- test_data %>%
  nest(data = !class, .by = class) %>%
  mutate(data = map(
    data, 
    \(d) count(distinct(d, id, gender), gender)
  ))
```

Results:

```
#> nested_test
# A tibble: 3 × 2
  class data            
  <chr> <list>          
1 h     <tibble [2 × 2]>
2 m     <tibble [2 × 2]>
3 s     <tibble [1 × 2]>

#> nested_test$data
[[1]]
# A tibble: 2 × 2
  gender     n
  <chr>  <int>
1 f          1
2 m          2

[[2]]
# A tibble: 2 × 2
  gender     n
  <chr>  <int>
1 f          1
2 m          1

[[3]]
# A tibble: 1 × 2
  gender     n
  <chr>  <int>
1 f          1
```

Comment: thank you this is exactly what I wanted to do! If you don't mind me asking, what does the \(d) do/mean in this context?

Comment: actually sorry but when I run your code, I can't replicate your output. When I print nested_test, I get tibble 1 x 2 data 2x2 and .by tibble 8x1. I also tried unnest() but that didn't produce it

Comment: Try updating to the latest version of tidyr. Alternatively, you could do `group_by(class) %>% nest(!class) %>% ungroup()`.

Comment: That works--thank you! Do you mind explaining what slash (d) does?

Comment: Actually, I figured out that it was calling an anonymous function and works the same as:     ~count(distinct(.x, id, gender), gender) works the same as     \(d) count(distinct(d, id, gender), gender)